# undefined reference to 'IMG_Load' and 'IMG_Init'

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw, sdl

I've been trying to figure out why those functions are undefined. I have been looking for hours trying to find a solution and haven't found any that worked. The closest one told me to download an earlier version of SDL_image, which worked but then told me SDL.dll was missing, insisting that I would need to use an older version of SDL.

Exact error message:

[image]

This is what my Makefile looks like:

```
g++ main.cpp -Isrc/include -Isrc/include/SDL2 -Iinclude/headers -Lsrc/lib -g -o main -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image
```

This is what my lib folder looks like:

[image]

And yes, the include folder does have SDL_image.h

Additional question, I want to put all my .dll files in a bin folder but I don't know what is telling what, where to look for them so I have them all in the src directory:

[image]

Comment: My guess would be that sdl is using the dll symbols by default but you're linking to the static library

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the exact error message.

Comment: Are the SDL libraries you are trying to link matching to the mingw version (both 32-bit or both 64-bit)?

Comment: the x86 is 32 bit right? @user7860670

Comment: yes, x86 is 32-bit

Comment: @user7860670 already have that down then, unless I should test out 64 bit but I'd doubt that works

Comment: Test both to be sure.

Answer (score -2):

Whoever comes across this error use the VC development libraries instead of the one for MinGW. For a reason I am not aware of it works.

Comment: Even if it appears to work, it sounds like a bad idea.